# cmake: LIBCLANG_PATH not found on windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, llvm-clang, libclang

I am trying to write a simple clang AST cursor traveler.

https://github.com/dyhe83/clang-AST-cursor-traveler

This following cmake code works fine on Linux.

```
PROJECT(traveler)

FIND_LIBRARY(LIBCLANG_PATH
    clang HINTS /usr/local/lib/
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(traveler 
    traveler.cpp
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(traveler
    ${LIBCLANG_PATH}
)
```

I also want to run this example on windows.

My LLVM is build in "C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM"
[image: folder]

But after I changed the FIND_LIBRARY part of CMakeLists.txt.

```
FIND_LIBRARY(LIBCLANG_PATH
    clang HINTS "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LLVM\\lib"
)
```

Some error occurs:

```
D:\WorkSpace\C\clang-AST-cursor-traveler\build>cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27025.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27025.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBCLANG_PATH
    linked by target "traveler" in directory D:/WorkSpace/C/clang-AST-cursor-traveler/src

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/WorkSpace/C/clang-AST-cursor-traveler/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

And "C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\lib" have the libraries.
[image: LibClang]

Does anyone know where is the correct clang library path on windows??

Comment: Is it not supposed to be `clang HINTS "C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/LLVM/lib"` ?

Comment: @super: in CMake no needs to escape spaces with `"\ "` - within double quotes the spaces are just spaces. But you are right that within CMake code "universal" path separator (`/`) is preferred.

Comment: I had tried ```clang HINTS "C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/LLVM/lib" ```, but still don't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to set env virable in windows.
I mean the place where you add/edit PATH env virables

LIBCLANG_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\lib